# Commutation calculation and interpretation of Dirac equation solution acting on a vacuum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, cosmology, wavefunction, dirac-equation

I have been solving this relatively simple problem of QFT:

$$<0|\psi_d(\vec{x})|\vec{p},s,c>$$

where

$$\psi_c(x)=\sum_s\int\frac{d^3p}{{(2\pi)}^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}} [b^s_{c,p}u^s(p)e^{ipx}+c^{s+}_{c,p}v^s(p)e^{-ipx}]$$

$$|p,s,c>=\sqrt{2E_p}b^{s+}_{c,p}|0>$$

As $<0|c^+b^+=0$, I get:

$$<0|\sum\int\frac{1}{{(2\pi)}^3}\sqrt{\frac{E_p}{E_q}} b^r_{d,q}b^{s+}_{c,p}u^r(q)e^{iqx}|0> $$

By anticommutation relation $$\{b^r, b^{s+}\}= {(2\pi)}^3\delta^{rs}\delta_{cd}\delta^{(3)}(p-q)$$ and $<0|b^+b=0$ I get:

$$<0|\sum_s\int d^3q\delta^{rs}\delta_{cd}\delta^{(3)}(q-p)u^r(q)e^{iqx}|0>=<0|\sum_s u^s(p)e^{ipx}|0>.$$

If I have not made a mistake in the calculation,I get something like a Dirac equation solution acting on a vacuum? Is this just a particle with some kind of spin and exact momenta $\vec{p}$ propagating through space or how to interpret it? Or have I made a mistake in the calculations somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computation you have is correct.

Note that nothing inside the $\langle 0 | \dots | 0 \rangle$ expectation value is an operator acting on the Hilbert space, except an implied identity coming from the anticommutator. You can take everything outside and use the fact that the vaccuum state is normalized to $1$ and you'll find that the thing you were computing is just the solution to the free classical wave equation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!